# Five Sided Polygon with custom length sides?

Tags: mesh

How do you input custom side lengths for a 5 sided polygon?

I enter in the Edit mode and whenever I select (using shift to select both sides of the 3D object) it alters the other sides (reference attached image). I would like the 5 sides to be: 72.94mm, 18.15mm, 34.16mm, 38.60mm and 37.55 mm.

There has to be some way to either lock, do a custom drawing and then use extrude, use a modifier, or way to enter in numerical data?

Any help greatly appreciated.[image: editmodepolygonblender]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Have you already tried the [Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/edit_mesh_tools.html) addon? There you can select an edge and set the length of it under [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8mrw.png) menu

Comment: @ Harry McKenzie I just open the Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools and I don't see any options in that which would allow for the desired object/measurements. I can't believe this is so difficult. Maybe is there a different software that is better suited for this task? There should be a UI interface in which you would select how many sides and could enter in the length of each side into fields, and then create the mesh (that would be too easy and make too much sense...).

Comment: It "would be too easy and make too much sense"? You do realize that you can create multiple pentagons from 5 edge lengths if you don't give at least one or more angles? And if you want to import a drawing, well create a vector sketch of that pentagon, save it as SVG file and import it into Blender. Then you have a curve which you can extrude and convert into a mesh or first convert, then extrude.

Comment: Gordon Brinkmann No I did not. Is there a link to another post, documentation or video to show this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem, as stated, is under-constrained. A couple of angles would define the shape; then you could use the intersections of circles on centred on the loose ends of segments 2 and 5 to find the convex point opposite side 1.

One way to explore the possible satisfactions of the constraints you ***have*** provided would be to set up two length-2  bone IK chains from a fixed base, with a common target.  (Displayed as orange wire, below):

[image]

The blue and green measured edges show 2 of infinite possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. I ended up drawing separate vertices in 2D with the length requirements and using Merge (at center) to create the 2D polygon, then extruding it into 3D. It worked.